# How to get cache records marked with quick-access keywords?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5

I'm looking for the following caching behavior, quite similar to cache tags but with a twist.

Let's pretend there's a cache method called `keywords()`. Consider the following code:

```
Cache::keywords(['user', 'general'])->put('key1', $value1, $minutes);
Cache::keywords('general')->put('key2', $value2, $minutes2);
```

This would store `$value1`in `key1` and `$value2`in `key2`, and they are both "marked" by their corresponding keywords.

Now here's the difference with cache tags: the keywords aren't ordered or constraining any following fluent calls. For example:

```
// Fetches value of key1, keywords are NOT required.
Cache::get('key1');

// Fetches value of key2, keywords are NOT required.
Cache::get('key2');

// Deletes all records using this keyword, viz. key1.
// key1 is completely out of cache storage, despite its other keyword.
Cache::keywords('user')->flush();

// Deletes all records using this keyword, viz. key1 and key2.
// key1 is completely out of cache storage, despite its other keyword.
Cache::keywords('general')->flush();
```

Is this possible out-of-the-box in Laravel?

If not, how could this be approached so that it is generic to all cache drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create a package myself:

https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-Cache-Keywords